# How can I create a View that shows nodes without a relation?

Tags: views, entities

On my site, all the nodes of content type **ABC** are supposed to have a relation (from the Relation module) to a user.

However, although the relations are usually created in Rules, somehow this didn't happen for some nodes, and to make it worse, it happened randomly (non-sequentially).

So, I would like to make a view that shows the nodes which do not have any relation-- but I can't figure out how to configure the view to do that.

If I add a **Relationship** of *Has relation Node -> User*, I can get all the nodes that DO have a relation, but how do I get all the nodes that DO NOT have a relation?

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a new filter criteria using your user reference field, and choose "Is empty (NULL)" as operator.

That will show all nodes that don't have any value in the user reference field.

Comment: I think you described the answer for Entity Reference module, but I am asking about the Relation module.

Comment: You're right; I mixed the two. Will have a look and update my answer if I find something.